# Copy information from a Excel file to another Excel file using SSIS VB2010, What wrong with these code

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, ssis

I am making an SSIS that will:

1. Copy data from SQL Server SQL to Excel file
2. Then from the Excel File into a another preexisting Excel file with some formulas

I did the  first part --Copy from SQL to *Excel1-*-  which works fine. Then I tried to copy from the *Excel1* file to the other using script task in Visual Basic 2010.

I want to somebody to check this program and tell me what is wrong with it in trying to copy information from a *Excel1* to a *Excel2*. When I executed I get the error `DTS scrip Task Runtime Error` and it does nothing.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim oExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application,
        oExel2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    Dim Obook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook,
        Obook2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook,
        Osheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet,
        Osheet2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    'Programing

    'From  Excel Spreadsheet

    oExcel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    oExcel.Visible = False
    Obook = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook("C:\Documents\AT1.xls")
    Osheet = DirectCast(Obook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)


    'To Excel Spreadsheet

    oExel2 = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    oExel2.Visible = False
    Obook2 = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook("C:\Documents\A2.xls")
    Osheet2 = DirectCast(Obook2.Sheets("January"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

    Osheet2.Range("B11", "R16").Value = Osheet.Range("A3", "Q8").Value

    'Close 

    Osheet = Nothing
    Obook.Close(False)
    oExcel.Quit()

    Osheet2 = Nothing
    Obook.Close(False)
    oExel2.Quit()

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

 End Sub
```

Comment: Which environment are you using to write this in, visual studio 2010? Have you tried using any of the debugging features?

Comment: Yes I doing a SSIS 2012 package, so is Visual Studio 2012 and the error is the follow Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. and a lot of stuff in a window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not really use Excel Interop in SSIS as it implies that you must install Excel on the server and that is not generally recommended. However this will do the trick...

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim oExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    Dim Obook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook, _
        Obook2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook, _
        Osheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet, _
        Osheet2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    oExcel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    oExcel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    oExcel.Visible = False

    Obook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\AT1.xls")
    Osheet = Obook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Obook2 = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()
    Osheet2 = Obook2.Worksheets.Item(1)
    Osheet2.Name = "January"

    Osheet2.Range("B11", "R16").Value = Osheet.Range("A3", "Q8").Value

    Obook2.SaveAs("C:\Documents\A2.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal)

    Obook.Close()
    Obook2.Close()
    oExcel.Quit()

End Sub
```

It would not be my choice, I'd probably use OLEDB instead.

To simply overwrite an existing workbook then...

```
Public Sub Main(ByVal Arguments() As String)

    Dim oExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    Dim Obook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook, _
        Obook2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook, _
        Osheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet, _
        Osheet2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    oExcel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    oExcel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    oExcel.Visible = False

    Obook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\AT1.xls")
    Osheet = Obook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Obook2 = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\A2.xls")
    Osheet2 = Obook2.Sheets("January")

    Osheet2.Range("B11", "R16").Value = Osheet.Range("A3", "Q8").Value

    Obook2.Save()

    Obook.Close()
    Obook2.Close()

    oExcel.Quit()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank so much, I will I used it,, I used Excel because I will take the information from SQL then to Excel and  then to Excel template

Comment: It will not work on a server unless the server has Excel installed. Installing Excel on a server has security implications.

Comment: Other way to do it? please let me know, remember from Excel to a Excel using SSIS

Comment: Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. these what happened when I run it

Comment: Have you set a break point and found out where the error occurs?

Comment: Nop, Where I can put one ?

Comment: Got it.. Ok now is working but I need to update the document no to create a new one, remember is a template document

Comment: That is trivial to change, won't you have a go? If not I'll do it tomorrow, I don't have anywhere to test it here.